# FindBugs reports bug instances without details

Tags: findbugs

In my pom.xml, the "findbugs-maven-plugin" is defined as

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includeTests>false</includeTests>
    <properties combine.self="merge" />
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

run `mvn clean install` on command line.  It reports 2 bug instances:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.3.2:check (default)
        on project sdf-pipeline: failed with 2 bugs and 0 errors -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

However, in the "findbugs.xml", it does not show the details of the bugs.

```xml
<file classname='com.xxx.A'></file>
<file classname='com.xxx.B'></file>
<Error></Error>
```

The maven I am using:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.2.0-35-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

1. What are the bugs?
2. Is this a bug in findbugs or something else?
3. When I run findbugs in Eclipse, it does not report any bugs.

Thanks for any input/comments

Comment: When I run "mvn findbugs:findbugs", it does not report bug instances, but instead report  "Warnings generated: 2".  Are these 2 warnings the 2 bug instances as reported in the output of "mvn clean install"?

Comment: BTW, the findbugs-maven-plugin is of 2.3.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the culprit is this.getClass().getresourceAsStream.  Both of the class A and B that FindBugs complains about have class.getResourceAsStream() in them.  Once I use this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(), FindBugs stops complaining.

I still don't know why mvn findbugs:findbugs it works fine.  I don't have time to further investigate it.  Will move on.